# How many of the users do know that they can receive notifications by clicking the star?

Tags: feature-request

Occasionally I see questions with plenty of upvotes, but without interesting answers yet. One could assume that most of the upvoters would be interested in an answer, yet there are usually only <50% as many stars as upvotes. That makes me believe that most people don't even know about this feature. Perhaps it would be worth to display a small explanation next to the star if a highly upvoted does not have a good answer yet.

Edit: I misunderstood something, please ignore.

Comment: How do you receive notifications for starred questions?

Comment: You haven't completely misunderstood, no. You have a counter of changes near  "favorites" in your profile.

Comment: And yet, despite all the downvotes, your post raises an interesting ancillary question: what can be changed to make question tracking easier?

Comment: @Deer the OP here asks clearly for one thing: show a popup "You can also star this question as favorite" when one is upvoting.

Comment: @ShadowWizard …thinking it would result in receiving notifications (like following a question on Quora).

Comment: I am confused by the number of downvotes. My question didn't do any harm, it was just a result of misinterpreting an answer elsewhere, and -1 points would have surely been enough to signal that my question is not worth reading.

Comment: If you mean you want to get notifications for changes in favorite questions it's a totally different thing, and I'm almost sure it has been asked before, I can have a look if you want.

Comment: Regarding downvotes: it means people disagree with your feature request, me being one of them. Your request in this question is (was?) clear to me: "display a small explanation next to the star..." - well, for me it's just noise. I don't want it. So since I disagree with the request, I downvote. Simple as that. That's how Meta works.

Comment: > *If you mean you want to get notifications for changes in favorite questions it's a totally different thing.* I thought SE would already be doing that, but apparently that was old information and the feature has been removed since.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a kernel of truth to what you write: too often we star a question but do not check whether it has been updated. Having a separate, low priority, low effort notification queue describing *what* exactly changed on our watchlist would be a good thing (**the effort of cycling through 20 accounts and hundreds of changed favorited questions is simply too large for the existing feature to be useful**).

Would be even better to be able to choose what **not** to watch in a particular question:

- I may be not interested in edits to the question but would be genuinely inclined to revisit it once a new upvoted answer is posted (with varying thresholds).
- I may want to re-read a particular answer (say, a canonical one) once it is edited.

EDIT: I understand that chances of getting this improvement are only marginally better than chances for meeting a talking tree. Here's hoping.

Comment: Yes, such a feature would be fantastic I think. Why are the chances slim?

Comment: @mcb - the devs are super-busy now.

Comment: What are they working on?

Comment: (: Voting for a new meta tag: [talking-tree]

Comment: Well, there was once such a thing called "envelope" - it used to lit up when there was a change in favorite question and I think it even listed all those changes. SE team (back then it was only Jeff) nuked it to dust at some point without giving any alternative.

Answer (score 8):

No, your base assumption is totally wrong in my opinion.

Personally, I upvote good questions, or in case of Meta bugs/requests I agree with. That does not mean that I want to make it favorite. Maybe 1 out of 10 questions are so good I would indeed like to keep track, but I really don't want any added noise for the 9 out of 10 questions I'm not interested in following.

Those who want can clearly see the star and its tooltip is very clear.

Comment: In addition to that, I favourite millions of questions in whose answers I am not even interested at all, and which I might have even downvoted. People often misinterpret favouriting as actually being, well, in favour of the question. But it's simply a way to keep track of the question, for whatever reason, even more so moderation and maintenance based reasons for me.